# is there any specific reason the syntax of for forEach is javascript is like this?

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

JavaScript noob Alert !!!
Is there any specific reason we represent the argument to the functions using [ ] brackets?

The syntax for the forEach function is like below

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue [, index [, array]]) {
    //your iterator
}[, thisArg]);
```

This is how it is represented on MDN

Why are we representing the syntax as it is and not simply

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue , index , array) {
    //your iterator
};
```

Also what is the  [, thisArg];

Comment: It is optional.

Comment: So the [, thisArg] was the way of representing an additional parameter which is the "this" (referenced object). But still why did they use such representation of parameters

Comment: To show optional [bracketed] parameters.

Comment: Yes. Now I see it. silly

Comment: This allows the documentation to be purely text and not depend upon colors or font styles to imply meaning. You can copy/paste this documentation and it still communicates that the parameters are optional.

Comment: And they add the recursive brackets to indicate that I cannot use "array" parameter without first adding the index paramter. It all makes sense now.

Comment: And the other thing was about the thisArg. so it can also be represented as `arr.forEach(callbackFxn{}, this) {}` where this would be the array itself as the second argument represented the 'this' reference to use

Answer (score 1):

This syntax typically indicates optional function parameters that are not necessary for the function to perform its primary task.  In the case of `arr.forEach()`, the index and the original array are not always necessary for the callback to perform its task.

This is actually a common syntax used in other languages (I know that PHP also does this in their documentation as well).

Comment: That explains a lot. Thanks @Informagician

Answer (score 0):

It shows that **index** **array** are optional parameters